# How can I add a new Layout to the new Form Ext. on TYPO3 8.7?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to use a new layout for the new form extension in TYPO3 8.6 LTS. The old way don't work:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {
    layout {
        types {
            form {
                removeItems = 900,910,920,930,940,950,999
                addItems {
                    800 = test
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The items to remove are shown, and the new item test, will don't show in Backend. Why? And how can I bring it to work?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.types.form_formframework{
//et cetera
```